# How to display different content depending on whether the app is opened first time?

Tags: android

How to display different content depending on whether the app is opened first time or the user setup something?

Imagine a activity A, B, If the user open the app first time or haven't setup something in activity B, Then display activity B, otherwise display activity A.

How to overcome this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html). In activity A add check for the preference `firstLaunch`. If it's not set, launch activity B. Then, in activity B, set it.

It could look like:

**Activity A**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // By default assume "true", which means this is the first launch.
    if (prefs.getBoolean("firstLaunch", true)) {
        // Start Activity B and finish myself.
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Activity B**

```
// Do it after you've initialized everything, so Activity A can be launched:
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
// Set "fistLaunch" to "false", so Activity A will start next time.
editor.putBoolean("firstLaunch", false);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but what do you mean by launch? use "startActivity" ?

Comment: Yes, I've expanded my answer with some code sample. Just note I wrote it by hand, so I might make some typo ;)

Comment: Sorry, but this finish() is needed? when I called it, it will finish activity B as well. but if commemted, the activity A will exists.

Comment: @AlexChan - no, `finish()` will only close activity which called it - activity A in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show different activity if user opened the app first time and different activity second or third time and so on then  you can use below approach.

*You can use the SharedPreference to achieve this.*

Check the condition like this in the Splash Activity :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefName", MODE_PRIVATE);
if(!preferences.getBoolean("isFirstRun", false)) {
    // This mean App Launch First Time
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit= preferences.edit();

    edit.putBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
    edit.commit();
    // Open the B Activity
} else {
    // This mean App Launch Second or third ... time and start the A Activity
}
```